# Genesis 25:25, what is the most accurate? KJV or DRB? If KJV, then, what is the Event of Simile?

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible

Genesis 25:25 (KJV):

> And the first came out red, all over like an hairy garment; and they called his name Esau.

Genesis 25:25 (DRB):

> He that came forth first was red, and hairy like a skin: and his name was called Esau. Immediately the other coming forth, held his brother's foot in his hand, and therefore he was called Jacob.

Genesis 25:25 (NLT):

> The first one was very red at birth and covered with thick hair like a fur coat. So they named him Esau.

What is the most accurate translation? KJV or DRB?

If KJV is the most accurate, then, what is the Event of Simile?, i.e: the Simile seems illogical, since there's no apparent logical Event (Event=similarity feature) between the Topic and the Vehicle.

It is accepted  logically to say "red like an apple, or, red like tomato", but it's  illogical  to say "red like a hairy garment".

In this verse- Genesis 25:25- are DRB faithful to and literal of the Latin Vulgate?

Why NLT (New Living Translation) seems very clear?

Comment: The difference here is merely the verse numbering.

Comment: @Dottard there's  a huge  difference between  KJV and DRB, the Simile in KJV seems  illogical.

Comment: They all contain a simile - "like".

Comment: @Dottard that's what  I am saying,  they all have  a simile, but it seems  illogical in KJV.

Comment: Then you should say why it appears illogical in the KJV and not the others

Comment: @Dottard Esau was  red like a hairy garment!!, the logical  simile should  be: hairy like a garment, not: red like a hairy garment.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the original Hebrew text followed by most English versions (KJV, NASB, NIV, TLV, ESV, etc) on the one hand, vs, the Latin text translated from the Hebrew of Jerome and Clementine, followed by DRB, is more apparent than real.

If we take the Gen 25:25, 26 together it will become clearer:

> Now the first came forth red, all over like a hairy garment; and they
>   named him Esau. [H] Afterward his brother came forth with his hand
>   holding on to Esau's heel, so his name was called Jacob.  [L] Isaac
>   was sixty years old when she gave birth to them.

The Hebrew text places the verse break between 25 and 26 at [H] above.  The Latin text places the verse break between 25 and 26 at [L] above.

Therefore, apart from the verse numbering, the meaning of the final English is almost identical.